# ProcessException build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Tags: linux, android-studio

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I changed to a linux O.S and now it is giving this error when i try run gradle:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':FFmpegAndroid:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/victor/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

Try:

Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/victor/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

Try:

Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a Linux version problem. Reading the error message, it appears that the runit install script expects upstart at one point, but my system (and I suspect yours) is running systemd.

Then I had a problem when trying to install lib32stdc++6 and lib32z1.

So i solved this problem with the solution pointed by this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/654951/failed-to-connect-to-socket-com-ubuntu-upstart-connection-refused-errors-were

Then I could successfully run this command `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing in my freshly install ubuntu 16.04.1. I just had to install both:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
```